# Python / Scripting: How do I create a text strip in the video editor

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

[This page](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SequencesMeta.html?highlight=new_effect#bpy.types.SequencesMeta.new_effect) suggests there is a function called `new_effect` that I could used to create a new text strip. However, this function is part of a class, so I can't just call `bpy.types.SequencesMeta.new_effect()` I have to find a object already in Blender that's a `bpy.types.SequencesMeta` class and use it. ...Where would I find such an object?

I could use `bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add()` but that function doesn't return the strip that was added, so to further edit that strip I'd have to go find it. Its possible but its annoying and makes me feel like I'm doing this the wrong way when the `new_effect()` function does return the newly created strip.

Answer (score 1):

The command is `bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_effect()`. This has the added bonus over `bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add()` that it can be called directly from the scripting console without throwing a `failed, context is incorrect` error.

Comment: To use this in any class method that has a `context` argument to an `execute` or `draw` function, remove the `bpy.`; so that the operator will be called in the same context that the class method is called in.